# MySQL returning value only for ID 1

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following query:

```
    SELECT      ur.repair_id, ur.repair_complete, ur.repair_noted_by_client, ur.repair_problem, ur.added_at, ur.added_by, ur.repaired_at, ur.repaired_by,
                aa.account_fullname AS added_by_name,
                ar.account_fullname AS repaired_by_name
    FROM        units_repairs AS ur
    LEFT JOIN   (SELECT account_id, account_fullname FROM accounts LIMIT 1) AS aa ON aa.account_id = ur.added_by
    LEFT JOIN   (SELECT account_id, account_fullname FROM accounts LIMIT 1) AS ar ON ar.account_id = ur.repaired_by
    WHERE       ur.unit_id = 1
```

It return the fullname only if the `account_id = 1`. If let say `repaired_by = 2` then it say `NULL`...

Thanks, I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining with inner query:

```
SELECT account_id, account_fullname FROM accounts LIMIT 1
```

where you have `LIMIT 1`, which gives you only one row (which probably has repaired_by = 1), and then you want to filter and get only rows where repaired_by is 2...and you don't have that one.

Comment: Thanks, it totally worked like a charm after I removed the LIMIT 1!

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are no records that satisfy the condition `repaired_by = 2` in the line,

```
 LEFT JOIN   (SELECT account_id, account_fullname FROM accounts LIMIT 1) AS ar ON ar.account_id = ur.repaired_by
```

Hence, `ar.account_id = ur.repaired_by` returns NULL.